# Headless Login: login and open remote session with cURL

Tags: php, session, curl, cookies, authentication

I am trying to use a button on my php web-application to launch a logged-in session on another website. In other words I want my application to:

1. open a new tab/window (achieved)
2. go to another website + login or
3. (alternatively) collect the session data needed for the target site to consider the current browser logged in.

This is achieved (in an incomplete manner with the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    print $result;
```

This successfully visualise the "logged-in" page of the remote site but whenever I click on any of the functionalities of such remote site I get and obvious 404. This is because I am just printing the output of the successful login via cURL and my browser is not dealing with the remote application on the target website. E.g. my address bar says I am in local.dev/loggedin.php instead of being at secure.targetsite.com/loggein.php.

This maybe helpful: Once logged-in via the browser, the target website sets a session cookie that allows the session to survive for a certain amount of time so that may also be useful. Can my web-application just fetch and store the session data from the auth procedure carried out by curl and use it to login?

This might not be possible to be done via cURL..

I was thinking of just parsing the response header for the cookie and use php setcookie() but it does not work: I get bounced by the remote app as if I was never logged in.

Please be patient, I am not an expert in the use of curl.

Comment: You are right, this isn't possible via cURL. And you can not set cookie for other domains either.

Comment: in which way would you approach this problem if you wanted to create a headless login to another website?

Answer (score 0):

I have done that for a few of my own applications, but it should work for almost anything that can be logged in via an html form submission. You can't use curl for this because it is running on your web server (whether that is on your local machine or in the cloud somewhere is irrelevant) and not actually being run by your browser. Your PHP application needs to open a new tab/window with a page that includes an HTML  that includes all necessary fields, method="get" or "post" as appropriate, and action="the destination login URL". Then just add an automatic form submission - e.g., with jQuery `$('#form_id').submit()` on page load.